# Checking if the result from tables is in sequence (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server

does anyone know how to check if the result set you got from a certain table is sequential or not, meaning which result came first and which one was resulted last.

Comment: What do you mean by "which result"? The rows?

Comment: By strict relational set theory, tables are **unordered** relations, which by definition don't have any concept of first or last at all. This request only has any meaning relative to a given `ORDER BY` expression.

Comment: Does "sequential" imply the order of row creation (i.e., insertion)?

Comment: Yes, the question has to do with column insertion. Imagine you're betting on soccer games and you pick teams that you think could win and get paid on that, but say your first 5 teams win and maybe the last team on your ticket loses. Normally you wouldn't get paid if that happens but I'm invernting a condition that say if your ticket wins atleast 5 games in a row e.g(team1, team2, team3, team4 and team5) I refund the panter but if  in any of those first 5 teams they is a losing one you not getting a refund. That what I wanna get to.

Comment: So, again, insertion order isn't a thing that really exists in a database. _The database is free to re-arrange the rows_, if they will match up that way better for an index (especially a clustered index). If this matters to you, you **must** also include a column indicating the timestamp or row order.